# Issue passing element into method

Tags: php, simplexml

For my own amusement, I am creating a XML reader class that utilizes PHP's `SimpleXMLElement` class. Eventually I will port this over to CodeIgniter as a library so I can utilize it in future applications. However, for now I am testing it using vanilla PHP. My end goal is to be able to traverse XML documents. For now, I am looking at this feed: http://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions.atom.

#### The issue

I am having difficulties passing information into my own `count()` method. Here is the method:

```
public function count($element) {
    $this->element = $element;
    return $this->xml->element->count();
}
```

The idea of the method above is to allow anyone to pass in an object and it would return an `int` that identifies the number of children that particular element has. Normally, this would work:

```
$xml->title->count(); // returns 1, for example
```

#### What has been Tried

```
echo $xml->count('entry'); // always results in 0

public function count($element) {
    return $this->xml->$element->count();
}

echo $xml->count('entry'); // still results in 0

echo $xml->count($xml->entry); // Undefined property
```

#### The Question

What is the correct approach to doing this? Any guidance would be appreciated! Here is the class in its entirety: http://pastebin.com/VjhjGcaR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the `count()` method like:

```
public function count($element) {
    return $this->xml->$element->count();
}
```

And using it like:

```
echo $xml->count('entry');
```

Will print `201` with the ATOM file in your example.

Did you really just try it with `foo`? If so, that explains the zero results.

Comment: Okay, question has been revised for the sake of clarity!

Comment: O_O maybe I was doing something wrong. I just tried it and it works. Thanks!